# avoid script to load multiple times for ajax's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load my content using ajax, says it's content.html. So in content.html there's a script tag. I found a problem with this approach. I do a `console.log('debug')` within content.html, and load it with ajax, and it trigger every time. How to do a flag to prevent that?

Note that I can't load the js of content.html in global scope dude to some plugin conflicts.

Comment: Could set flag variable and check that before executing the code. if it's all events...can use off() before calling on(). How you manage it partly depends on that your code does

Comment: Is `content.html` calling `content.html` ?

Comment: Check here.... Maybe it's your situation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062450/passing-variable-from-javascript-to-php-with-ajax-post-method/38062622#38062622

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No. Assume layout.html has the ajax call.

Comment: @charlietfl on() and off() to bind something? imagine I have a script tag within my content.html, it got loaded after the ajax of layout.html is done.

Comment: No ....  off() then on() so if you do load script more than once you remove previous listeners before adding new ones.  `$(selector).off('click').on('click', function...`

Comment: Can also only target the new html by looking inside parent container only. Again.. what you do depends a bit on what code is used for

Answer (score 0):

It's only an idea... since we didn't see anycode yet...
And I'm still not sure what the problem really is.

If you want to leave this script in `content.hmtl` but disable it when called by `layout.html`.

You could do something like this in `layout.html`:

```
$("script").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("src")=="[particular source]"){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Or use an `id` if there is no `src` attribute.
This has to run after you got the ajax result....

Comment: I don't include script in layout.html. I include script in content.html.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue.
Chrome load the js many times with unique VM files and execute all of them when the html in ajax is loaded.